# How to find the view page from the url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have downloaded a project from server which is in `codeigniter`.
I want to edit some pages.

The problem is I am unable to find a specific page from the URL. How can I find a specific page from the URL to make changes to that specific page?

There are multiple folders inside view, e.g., `http://localhost/TMO/CMS/company/6/admin/store`

How do I find which page is viewed at this URL?

Comment: Go to routes page and check whether which controller it is linked..

Comment: You need to check you routes,as all controller are linked there and then you have to find the controller and its method and then you can view it file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in Codeigniter is not related to the name or location of the views. Views are called from within the controller, so if it's the view you're interested in, you will have to find the controller that calls it first.

By default the url is domain.com/[controller]/[method] where [controller] and [method] are the name of the controller and method responsible for generating a specific web page.

However, the example URL you gave does not follow this pattern so it must have been created using a custom route. To find the custom routes look in the file application/config/routes.php, in that file will be a list of all URL routes and the controller and method they point to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow few steps :

- Check the `routes` and map route with `controller` and its `function`
- Trace that `controller` file and find the function's code
- In that function, check the loaded `view` file
- Then Move to that view file in `Views`

Comment: there are multiple control files which one to check.

Comment: You need to check in routes. something matching with the pattern : TMO/CMS/company/6/admin/store

Comment: i also have some links like '<?php echo $modulo->titulo_registro; ?>' can u tell me where this $modulo is defined so i can modify its value

Comment: Check Config.php file or find in whole directory that where its defined.